# IntelliJ 2018.1 "Esc" shortcut stopped working

Tags: intellij-idea

After update to IntelliJ 2018.1 the <kbd>Esc</kbd> shortcut (which is correctly key-mapped to "escape" in the settings) isn't able to set back the focus on the editor window.

Does this happened to me only? Someone have a solution to repristinate that functionality?

Comment: Please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-186820.

Comment: Hi, thank you seems exactly this the issue I'm having, added my comment there  :) thank you

Comment: If I understand it right, there's no solution to this problem yet :(

Comment: You get a vote up for 'repristinate'!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem on i3wm,
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000177984-Focus-issue-with-Intellij-Idea-2018-1

I want also to add that sometimes after opening new project I have to restart the i3wm environemnt ( there is a shortcut that  does that )